# mySQL Group By query not working

Tags: mysql

I want to join the tables below. I have query:

```
SELECT MAX(s.Date) AS last_ship_date,
    s.Form AS summary_form, 
    SUM(s.Total) AS qty_ship,
    SUM(f.Quantity) AS qty_req
    FROM Slip AS s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Forms AS f ON s.Form=f.Form
    AND s.DocketNumber=f.DocketNumber
    WHERE s.DocketNumber=20491
    GROUP BY s.Form
```

This query gives **qty_req** for English as 210000, while what I want is 105000. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I *want* to have multiples in both tables. That is why I am using SUM. I want to aggregate it by form.

NOTE: If I just execute the following, then I get 105000 for English, just like I want.

```
SELECT SUM(f.Quantity) AS qty_req FROM Forms AS f
WHERE f.DocketNumber=20491 
GROUP BY f.Form
```

**Table Forms**

```
| Form    | Quantity | DocketNumber | Date
| English | 105000| 20491
| French  | 105000 | 20491
```

**Table Slip**

```
| Form    | DocketNumber | Total | Date
| English | 20491        | 7000
| English | 20491        | 1000
| English | 20491        | 1000
| French  | 20491        | 7000
```

Answer (score 0):

LEFT OUTER JOIN Forms AS f ON s.Form=f.Form
    AND s.DocketNumber=f.DocketNumber

This join results in multiple matches per slip if I read your table values correctly, which would cause it to sum the same values multiple times.

Comment: That depends on your data and the usage. It's isn't broken per se; your data has multiples. If it shouldn't, fix the data and put a primary key in there. If it should, you need to decide how to get the record you wanted (a TOP 1 or whatever). Otherwise, the number IS correct.

Comment: And I do want to have multiple entries for the same form. That is why I am summing them.